# Why I can't use string.charCodeAt() at elements of reduce callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reduce

I have the following code for trying to get the total sum of the charCodes of one word. (Why I need that isn't important for my question)

```
function codepoints(string) {
    return string.split("").reduce((arr, next) => arr.charCodeAt(0) + next.charCodeAt(0))
}
console.log(codepoints("abc"));
```

But JavaScript is giving me the error:

> arr.charCodeAt is not a function

When asking the type of 'arr', it is a string. But why I can not use the method charCodeAt on it?

Comment: `.charCodeAt()` returns a **number**, so the second time through the callback `arr` will be a number not a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making two mistakes.

- You don't need to apply `charCodeAt` on array its `Number`(sum of char codes).
- Also pass `0` as second argument to `reduce()` which will be the initial value of `arr`

```js
function codepoints(string) {
    return string.split('').reduce( (arr,next) => arr + next.charCodeAt(0),0)
}
console.log(codepoints("abc"));
```

**Note**: the variable name `arr` is not correct for situation. Use `sum` or `ac` or something like that.

Comment: Your spread solution doesn't appear to be correct. For each surrogate pair, you add the first element and ignore the second.

Comment: @georg Can't get what you mean. But I have read that `split()` unicode unsafe we should use `...` in case of that. `'❤'.split('') => [ "�",  "�",  "�", "�",  "❤"]` which is wrong I think.

Comment: Your string is `\ud83d\udc0e\ud83d\udc71\u2764`, your result is 120798, which is `0xd83d + 0xd83d + 0x2764`

Comment: @georg I got it I am wrong.So this means `split()` works fine?

Comment: @georg Ok i removed the extra part of it as it was wrong. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 5):

You are not using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) correctly, the first parameter of the callback is the partial result or accumulator.

The `Array.reduce` takes a *callback* function which itself takes four more parameters, in your case you need the *first two*.

The syntax of the `reduce` function is `reduce(callback[, initialValue])`:

> **callback** Function to execute on each element in the array, taking four arguments:
>
> **accumulator** The accumulator accumulates the callback's return values; it is the accumulated value previously returned in the last
>   invocation of the callback, or initialValue, if supplied (see below).
>
> **currentValue** The current element being processed in the array.**
>
> **initialValue** Optional Value to use as the first argument to the first
>   call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first
>   element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array
>   without an initial value is an error.

To find the sum pass an initial value of 0 and then the add the subsequent elements in the array to it:

```js
function codepoints(string) {
    return string.split('').reduce( (acc,next) => acc + next.charCodeAt(0), 0)
}

console.log(codepoints("abc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do not specify *initialValue* whel calling [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) then:

- `accumulator` will contain the first array element on first iteration
- `accumulator` will contain the accumulated values on subsequent iterations

In your example you can check the accumulator variable and sum accordingly:

```js
function codepoints(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reduce((acc, next) => (typeof acc === "string" ? acc.charCodeAt(0) : acc) + next.charCodeAt(0))
}

console.log(codepoints("abc"));
```